# Error while trying to print the pdf file

Tags: c#, .net, acrobat

I was trying to print a pdf document in the background using a console application. I used the process for doing it. The console application sends the pdf file to the printer, But the adobe reader that is opened in the background in minimized mode is throwing the following error "There was an error opening this document. This file cannot be found". As a result of this while printing multiple times, I was not able to kill the process. Is there any possibility of getting rid of this error? 
My requirement is to print the pdf file using process and while doing that the pdf file must be opened in the minimized mode and once done printing the reader needs to be closed automatically. I have tried the following code, but still throws the error..

```
string file = "D:\\hat.pdf"; 
PrinterSettings ps = new PrinterSettings();
string printer = ps.PrinterName;
Process.Start(Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKe(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion"+@"\App Paths\AcroRd32.exe").GetValue("").ToString(),string.Format("/h /t \"{0}\" \"{1}\"", file, printer));
```

Answer (score 0):

since you want to have Acrobat reader open in the background when you want to print the document, you could use something like:

```
private static void RunExecutable(string executable, string arguments) 
{
   ProcessStartInfo starter = new ProcessStartInfo(executable, arguments);
   starter.CreateNoWindow = true;
   starter.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   starter.UseShellExecute = false;

   Process process = new Process();
   process.StartInfo = starter;
   process.Start();

  StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
  using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput) 
  {
    string line = reader.ReadLine();
    while (line != null) 
    {
      buffer.Append(line);
      buffer.Append(Environment.NewLine);
      line = reader.ReadLine();
      Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
  }
  if (process.ExitCode != 0) 
 {
    throw new Exception(string.Format(@"""{0}"" exited with ExitCode {1}. Output: {2}", 
executable, process.ExitCode, buffer.ToString());  
 }
```

}

You can print your PDF by incorporating the above code into your project and using it as follows:

```
string pathToExecutable = "c:\...\acrord32.exe";
RunExecutable(pathToExecutable, @"/t ""mytest.pdf"" ""My Windows PrinterName""");
```

this code was taken from http://aspalliance.com/514_CodeSnip_Printing_PDF_from_NET.all

If you do not need to have Acrobat Reader open in the background, and just print the pdf like any other document, you can have a look at the PrintDocument class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.print.aspx